# Chatroom related tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, chat

It would be nice to create an association between tags and a chat, so that when you are viewing questions for a particular tag you get a recommendation for a relevant chat room. Similar to how the chat rooms are displayed in the right column on meta.

For example, with the **WPF** tag you might be shown the **C#** and **WPF** chat rooms

Comment: +1 - it's one of those ideas that I wanted to suggest but it always escaped me.  There's no current way of applying tags to a chat room, but if there were it would be easy to handle the association from there.

Comment: yeh, it bugs me how quiet the chat rooms are when they have the potential to be really useful

Comment: Honestly I think that's because the chat system isn't made terribly obvious. It feels kind of like a hidden extra. Even when I see people chatting in the sidebar, it isn't clear that it's something you can do right in the browser. I was expecting an IRC room or something so I didn't even bother clicking for quite some time. That said, I like chat when I do use it, and I think it works pretty well.